# Fullscreen Flexslider using background images

Tags: jquery, css, flexslider

I have a Flexslider that I want to make fullscreen. All parent divs are set to 100% but the responsive side of Flexslider is making the image stay in it's aspect.

I've set the image to be a background-image of the li with the background-size set to cover. The image fills the width and according to the DOM the li is 100% height but there's a white border at the bottom of the image.

How can I get the background-image to fill the entire screen?

Turning off background-repeat makes it fill the entire screen but how can I get it to stretch the image to fill the space?

Comment: It would be much easier to see what's going wrong with a demo or some code...

Comment: Having some code would really help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a background image you're trying to make fit then i would suggest using `background-size: cover;`

Comment: D'oh, even though I mentioned in the question I had it set to cover, in the code I didn't actually add it! Stupid mistake!